# What is the best way to get keyboard events (input without press 'enter') in a Ruby console application?

Tags: ruby, io, console

I've been looking for this answer in the internet for a while and have found other people asking the same thing, even here. So this post will be a presentation of my case and a response to the "solutions" that I have found.

I am such new in Ruby, but for learning purposes I decided to create a gem, [here](https://github.com/fschuindt/camelog).
I am trying to implement a keyboard navigation to this program, that will allow the user use short-cuts to select what kind of request he want to see. And in the future, arrow navigations, etc.

My problem: I can't find a consistent way to get the keyboard events from the user's console with Ruby.

Solutions that I have tried:

1. Highline gem: Seems do not support this feature anymore. Anyway it uses the STDIN, keep reading.
2. STDIN.getch: I need to run it in a parallel loop, because at the same time that the user can use a short-cut, more data can be created and the program needs to show it. And well, I display formated text in the console, (Rails log). When this loop is running, my text lost the all the format.
3. Curses: Cool but I need to set position(x,y) to display my text every time? It will get confusing.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/fschuindt/5567063#file-camelog-rb-L43) is where I am trying to do it.
You may note that I am using "stty -raw echo" (turns raw off) before show my text and "stty raw -echo" (turns raw on) after. That keeps my text formated.

But my key listener loop is not working. I mean, It works in sometimes but is not consistent. If a press a key twice it don't work anymore and sometimes it stops alone too.

Let me put one part of the code here:

```
    def run
    # Two loops run in parallel using Threads.
    # stream_log loops like a normal stream in the file, but it also parser the text.
    # break it into requests and store in @requests_queue.
    # stream_parsed_log stream inside the @requests_queue and shows it in the screen.
    @requests_queue = Queue.new
    @all_requests = Array.new
    # It's not working yet.
    Thread.new { listen_keyboard }
    Thread.new { stream_log }
    stream_parsed_log
  end

  def listen_keyboard
    # not finished
    loop do
      char = STDIN.getch
      case char
      when 'q'
        puts "Exiting."
        exit
      when 'a'
        @types_to_show = ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'ASSET']
        requests_to_show = filter_to_show(@all_requests)
        command = true
      when 'p'
        @types_to_show = ['POST']
        requests_to_show = filter_to_show(@all_requests)
        command = true
      end
      clear_screen if command
      @requests_queue += requests_to_show if command
      command = false
    end
  end
```

I need a light in my path, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

That one was my mistake.
It's just a logic error in another part of code that was running in another thread so the ruby don't shows the error by default. I used ruby -d and realized what was wrong. This mistake was messing my keyboard input.

So now it's fixed and I am using STDIN.getch with no problem.
I just turn the raw mode off before show any string. And everything is ok.

You can check [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5581474#file-camelog-rb-L219), or in the [gem](https://github.com/fschuindt/camelog) itself.

That's it.