# How to terminate the loop if user press any key in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, loops, terminate

As title says, I want to terminate loop if user press any key.
Any key means if user simply press keyboard letter, 'A' and not press 'enter' after 'A', it should terminate the infinite loop. I did little research, and found out that using Thread is a key-point to solve this problem. However, since I just started learning Ruby a week ago, I just have no idea how to code tbh.

```
Thread.new do
  while user_input = STDIN.gets
    break if user_input.chomp == true # dont know what to write here
  end
end

loop do
  random = random_number(0,1)
  puts random
  total = random + total
  count += 1
  sleep 1
end
```

This is code I have now, and of course its not working..
I need help...(I am worrying that Thread has to be done with 'Enter'. Like it terminates loop when user press 'any key' and 'Enter'.. And that is not what I want)

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems here.

1. The first is that `gets` demands that you hit enter when you're finished typing. You can fix this by using the `getch` method from the `io/console` module.
2. The second is that your loop isn't inside your thread. `break` escapes from inside a loop, it doesn't kill all running loops.

Here's a very simple demonstration of how this works:

```
require 'io/console'

def echo_keyboard_input
    loop do
      char = STDIN.getch
      puts char
      break if char == 'q'
    end
end

t = Thread.new { echo_keyboard_input }    
t.join
```

This program just echoes characters you type in back to you, one at a time, and exits when you type 'q'. (I based it on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16518493/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-keyboard-events-input-without-press-enter-in-a-r).)

However, this is a very advanced thing to be trying with so little experience; threads can be quite tricky to work with even for experienced programmers. if you really want to focus on something else, you might want to find a ruby gem that makes this easier.